# GWT doesn't apply a Css style when client is IE8

Tags: css, gwt, internet-explorer-8, cssresource

i've this css class:

```
.defaultActionButton {
height: auto;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 6px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
white-space: normal;
border: 1px solid #3079ed;
border-radious: 2px;
font-size: 13px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;

background: #4d90fe; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #4d90fe 0%, #4d87ed 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#4d90fe), color-stop(100%,#4d87ed)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #4d90fe 0%,#4d87ed 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #4d90fe 0%,#4d87ed 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #4d90fe 0%,#4d87ed 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #4d90fe 0%,#4d87ed 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4d90fe', endColorstr='#4d87ed',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
filter: none;
<![endif]-->
}
```

This class is loaded by a GWT CssResource:

```
interface Common extends CssResource {
            //cut
    String defaultActionButton();
            //cut
}
```

applied with this line:

```
loginButton.addStyleName(Styles.INSTANCE.common().defaultActionButton());
```

This works correctly with Chome, Firefox and IE9:
[image: styleOk]
but with IE8 this style is not applied and the button is ugly: [image: styleKo]

(border-radius is not supported by IE8, but it's not a problem).

By the way, copying the css style class to a plain HTML file that contains only a simple button, also IE8 displays it well: [image: styleOkIE8simpleHtml]

How can I have the same result "inside" GWT?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you just look with IE developer tool which properties are applied... in IE8

Comment: Nice guess, but from work i cant download the plugin because of proxy and i cant find the standalone installer.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you get the solution to this?

Comment: I surrendered: completely removed IE8 support from my project...

Answer (score 0):

I did it in my project and it's working in IE8.
You have to write following line in your CSS.

```
border-collapse: separate !important;
```